# how to rewind & pause video streaming with JMeter and play it again

Tags: jmeter, video-streaming, performance-testing, load-testing

I have 2 questions:

- I'd like to know how to pause a video streaming with Jmeter and then play it again during the Jmeter Test.
- and how to rewind the video streaming to a certain position (time), and then play it again during the Jmeter test

I use to HLS Plugin to load test the video streaming

- Apache Jmeter version : 5.2.1
- HLS Plugin: 3.0.1
- OS: Win 10-64 Bit
- Java Version:  OpenJDK 1.8 (64 Bit)

Answer (score 0):

- pause video streaming: according to [JMeter HLS Plugin 3.0 is out!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/HLS-3.0-Release) article:

  > Resuming download between iterations:
  >
  > Check resume video download between iterations in case you want the plugin to download from where it left off in the last iteration.
  >
  > [image]
  >
  > For a better understanding of this point, l**et's say we set a video duration to 5 seconds in the sampler. If we check the resume video download between iterations option and play start, the first iteration will download until it reaches the 5th second, the following iteration will start from that point (second 5) until it reaches 10 seconds, and it will keep doing so until all the iterations end or the video ends.**

  so you can introduce a delay between Thread Group iterations using i.e. [Flow Control Action sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action)
- rewind - both [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) and [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) are basically playlists of video/audio chunks so there is no "rewind" concept, you can just start over the playback